# How to make SWT Table in CheckboxTableViewer scrollable?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I couldn't find any answers for this special case (using `CheckboxTableViewer`), so I hope it's not a duplicate.

I have the following `createPartControl()` in an Eclipse view (3.x).

I'm trying to display two buttons and a checkable table in a `GridLayout`, as below

```
-------------------
| Button | Button |
-------------------
|      Table      |
-------------------
```

Nothing spectacular. Everything is displayed fine so far. My table is embedded within a `CheckboxTableViewer`, has a single column and sometimes the content (`String`) is longer than the column width. So I'm trying to make the `Table` (got via `viewer.getTable()`, not explicitly constructed!) scrollable to make all content available. This doesn't work and I cannot understand why.

I have played around with `SWT` style bits (`SWT.H_SCROLL`, `SWT.V_SCROLL`), I've tried a `ScrollableComponent`, but to no avail. I couldn't get the `ScrolledComponent` to work because I'm not constructing my table explicitly, and thus couldn't `setContents()` properly.

Below is the gist of my `createPartControl()`.

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    addSelectionButtons(parent); // Works

    myTableViewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    myTableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 2, 1));

    Table myTable = (Table) myTableViewer.getControl();
    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout();
    tableLayout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(100, 50, true));
    myTable.setLayout(tableLayout);

    myTableViewer.setContentProvider(new MyContentProvider());

    TableViewerColumn viewerCol = new TableViewerColumn(myTableViewer, SWT.LEFT);
    TableColumn col = viewerCol.getColumn();
    col.setText("My column");
    viewerCol.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return text; // Dummy var
        }
    });

    myTableViewer.setInput(getInput()); // Gets model
    myTableViewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
    myTableViewer.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);
}
```

I know this is borderline "give me teh codez", but I really cannot find the issue with this setup.

Comment: Does `CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL` not work?

Comment: @greg-449: No, it doesn't. It does indeed give me a vertical scrollbar on the viewer, but I cannot scroll past what I think is the "original cut-off point" of the table. Does that make sense? I think it might be to do with the `ColumnWeightData` I set on the table, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Are you aware that - given the table has only one column - you can omit creating a column at all?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann: I wasn't (really) aware that I wouldn't need to create a column for a one-col table. However, as I want to have a column header for the one column I have, I think I still need to create one after all.

Comment: Understood. Not sure what you tried so far thus I'll suggest what comes to my mind: If you stay with creating columns, be aware that the `TableLayout` _is only valid until the table is resized_. Otherwise you'll need a `TableColumnLayout` to maintain column sizes. Be aware that it has to be added to a contains whose only child is the table. If that doesn't help, can you post a screenshot of the table with its not-scrolling content?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann: Thanks, [I've managed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28509756/731040) without having to resort to either `TableLayout` and `TableColumnLayout` after all. Not making things too complicated turned out to be the crux of the matter (again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue by going back to square one and re-implementing in the most generic fashion I could find documented. I.e.:

- I've added a proper `LabelProvider` (and got rid of the `ColumnLabelProvider`),
- set a simple `GridData` layout data object to the table (and otherwise haven't messed with it),
- and simplified the `TableColumn` section a lot (despite having only one column in the table, I still need to declare a `TableColumn` to be able to set a column heading). **Note:** The `TableColumn` must be `pack()`ed, otherwise the content doesn't show. From the [`TableColumn` API](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FTableColumn.html): "*Causes the receiver to be resized to its preferred size.*"

Simple and working.

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
  parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

  addSelectionButtons(parent); // Adds select/deselect all buttons

  myTableViewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
  myTableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
  myTableViewer.setContentProvider(new MyContentProvider());
  myTableViewer.setLabelProvider(new MyLabelProvider());
  myTableViewer.setInput(getInput()); // Gets model

  TableColumn column = new TableColumn(myTableViewer.getTable(), SWT.FILL);
  column.setText("My column");
  column.pack();

  myTableViewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
  myTableViewer.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);
}
```